# Was Latin A Nasalized Language?

Tags: latin, vowels, romance-languages, nasals

Thinking about it, most of the Romance languages I have heard nasalize vowels quite frequently and it seems consistent: that has me wondering, is there any evidence to show that Latin was a heavily-nasalized language?

Comment: It's plausible that nasalized vowel *phones* existed in Latin at some point or another. Vowels in proximity to nasal consonants are often allophonically nasalized in various languages: e.g. in English the vowel in "hand" is typically somewhat nasalized. But assimilative allophonic variants like this are often not noted in descriptions of a language, so as far as I know we don't have good evidence about it. See Alex B.'s answer to the following question on Latin SE: [Did an internal m nasalize the preceding vowel?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1974)

Comment: As far as I know, no extant ancient description of Latin pronunciation clearly describes a three-way contrast in a synchronic phonology of Latin between nasal vowels, sequences of a vowel + nasal stop, and non-nasalized long vowels. We have evidence for the elision of word-final "-um, -am, -em" and for the loss of "n" before /f/ or /s/ (with compensatory lengthening of the preceding vowel), but these sound changes don't necessarily require a stable intermediate stage with nasalized vowel *phonemes.*

Comment: Possibly helpful: "Nasal Vowel Evolution in Romance", https://muse.jhu.edu/article/19215

Comment: I'm curious about the Latin -iō suffix, which is inflected -iōnis, -iōnes, -iōnum, etc., and is reflected as -ión/-iones in Spanish, -ão/-ões in Portuguese, -ion/-ions in French, -ione/-ioni in Italian, -ie/ii or -iune/-iuni in Romanian, etc.